# Compiling Java code under Android in runtime

Tags: android, runtime-compilation, dexmaker

I have a class name String and a String which  containing the class code. For example, "Example" is the name of the class, and

```
public class Example {
    public void example () {System.out.println ("Hello world!"); }
}
```

The class code.

I looked at the Dexmaker library, but I did not understand if it's possible to compile the generated code into it. And the question is just how to compile the code string under Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one true way: using [DexMaker](https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker). All examples you can find on [DexMaker wiki](https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker/blob/master/README.md) and especially for [current problem (runtime generation code on android)](https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker#runtime-code-generation).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if possible at all the compilation within the embedded system but definitelly you can parse and run the code using beanshell:
http://www.beanshell.org/

it is lightweight and easily to embed in your app. Then you can instance the generated class and run whatever you put inside.